# Linking to another html page is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

I tried to link the settings tab as shown in the sidebar to a new HTML page called (settings.html), but when I click on the settings it does not direct me to the (settings.html) page.

[settings tab on the sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lcggz.png)
[sidebar code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh7zy.png)

Both HTML pages use the same external JavaScript file, and I only was able to navigate to the settings page from the sidebar, when I removed the JavaScript file from the HTML code.

This is the website code on GitHub
[https://github.com/Jehad-Sauafth/Dashboard.git]

Comment: Hi abood and welcome to stackoverflow. Please share your code that triggers the link to your settings page so we can take a look at it to see what your problem is. From your screenshot i can only assume that your url is not correct because you are redirecting to a page with # as your link.

Comment: @snpz
I added an image of the sidebar code to the post.
The whole code is also attached in the post as a GitHub link.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your JavaScript is preventing the default behaviour of all a-elements.

put the `e.preventDefault()` into the if-statements, so the default behaviour is only prevented for jump-links.

```
const allLinks = document.querySelectorAll("a:link");

allLinks.forEach(function (link) {
  link.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    const href = link.getAttribute("href");

    // Scroll back to top
    if (href === "#") { 
      e.preventDefault();
      window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        behavior: "smooth",
      });
    }
    //Scroll to other links
    if (href !== "#" && href.startsWith("#")) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const sectionEl = document.querySelector(href);
      sectionEl.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    }
  });
});
```